# ModelSim Fatal error in process RAM_i1/RAM_0_0_0/P107 Lattice MACHXO3L_MISC.vhd

Tags: fpga, lattice, modelsim

I am facing a fatal error when trying to simulate in ModelSim a design that instantiates a RAM IP for the target device MACHXO3L from Lattice Semiconductor. I have compiled their libraries to use in ModelSim, but the simulations always stop due to the following fatal error:

```
# ** Fatal: (vsim-3483) Delay in signal assignment is not ascending.
#    Time: 20 ns  Iteration: 1  Process: /fft_tb/fft_i/RAM_i1/RAM_0_0_0/P107 File: C:/lscc/diamond/3.11_x64/cae_library/simulation/script/../vhdl/machxo3l/src/MACHXO3L_MISC.vhd Line: 541
# Fatal error in Process P107 at C:/lscc/diamond/3.11_x64/cae_library/simulation/script/../vhdl/machxo3l/src/MACHXO3L_MISC.vhd line 541
```

ModelSim Fatal Error:
[image: ModelSim Fatal Error]

Any ideas? It seems that the problem is the Lattice library MACHXO3L_MISC.vhd line 541

Comment: Your errors are behind links, which means they can't be searched by people who have the same errors as you in the future. Please have a read of [this guide on producing code for a good quality question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), then include and mark up your errors in your question. Cheers!

Comment: IEEE Std 1076-2008 5.2.4.2 Predefined physical types "Any TIME value whose absolute value is smaller than this limit is truncated to zero (0) time units."  10.5.2.2 Executing a simple assignment statement "It is an error if the sequence of new transactions is not in ascending order with respect to time." This run-time error may be caused by the simulation resolution limit set to ns, resulting in these two new transactions not meeting the 10.5.2.2 rule. Note the previous line in the console output picture: `** Fatal: (vsim-3483) Delay in signal assignment not ascending.` Provide a [mcve].

Comment: Do you guys realize that this is VHDL and not a common language that I could provide a minimal reproducible example? It is a problem with the Lattice libraries, It is impossible to write the whole library here in the post or some minimal reproducible example. I agree that I should have pasted the error message though.

Comment: If you had tried to produce a [mcve] you would have found you'd have only required process P107 and stimulus (20 - 30 ns worth). The value to you and future readers is in reproducing the error and demonstrating the fix. Lacking the [mcve] and having never supplied the original resolution limit you've denied anyone else the ability to answer. (Rather just guessing.)

Comment: And no it's not a library problem. We used to call that an operator error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As correctly suggested by @user1155120, the problem is solved by changing the simulation time resolution. I changed it to picoseconds by modifying the modelsim.ini file. The parameter to be modified is:

```
; Set SystemC default time unit.
; Set to fs, ps, ns, us, ms, or sec with optional 
; prefix of 1, 10, or 100.  The default is 1 ns.
; The ScTimeUnit value is honored if it is coarser than Resolution.
; If ScTimeUnit is finer than Resolution, it is set to the value
; of Resolution. For example, if Resolution is 100ps and ScTimeUnit is ns,
; then the default time unit will be 1 ns.  However if Resolution 
; is 10 ns and ScTimeUnit is ns, then the default time unit will be 10 ns.
ScTimeUnit = ps
```

You may also want or need to change the same parameter in the .mpf file, in your project folder. 
If that doesn't change the simulation resolution you can implicitly do it in the vsim command:

```
vsim work.<your_test_bench> -t ps
```

Comment: Note lacking a [mcve] your readers can't determine the usefulness of manipulating the SystemC simulator parameter for a VHDL model.